# Windows Store Application Metronome Stop Button Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Hello there i am developing Windows Store App.

First of all, here is my code:

```
public class TickArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class Metronome
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    public event TickHandler Tick;
    public delegate void TickHandler(Metronome m, TickArgs e);

    public Metronome()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (Tick != null)
        {
            Tick(this, new TickArgs { Time = DateTime.Now });
        }
    }

    public void Start(int bbm)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 / bbm);
        _timer.Start();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Start();
    }
}

public class Listener
{
    public void Subscribe(Metronome m, MediaElement mmx)
    {
        m.Tick += (mm, e) => mmx.Play();
    }
    public void UnSubscribe(Metronome m, MediaElement mmx)
    {
        m.Tick += (mm, e) => mmx.Stop(); 
    }
}
```

To start metronome i use these codes:

```
l.Subscribe(m, mediaelement);
m.Start(120);
```

This works perfectly fine.

To stop metronome i use these codes:

```
l.UnSubscribe(m, mediaelement);
m.Stop();
```

Metronome stops **BUT** if i try to start again, it just does not start. What should i do?

I would appreciate your helps.

My regards...

Comment: Why do you start the timer immediately after stopping the timer in the `Stop()` method?

Comment: Also, your subscribe and unsubscribe appear to always be adding handlers and never removing them. Is this intended? You may want to look into something like WeakEventHandler.

Comment: @NateDiamond Hello, thanks for answer. However if i don't start timer after stopping the timer, the sound file does not stop playing.

About subscribe and unsubscribe, it is not intended. Probably the error is because of that, what should i do to fix it? I could not figure it out really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I've just made small changes in start and stop methods:

```
public void Start(int bbm)
{
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
    _timer.Start();
}
public void Stop()
{
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Now it works perfectly fine.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so what you have done is you've subscribed your metronome to two handlers, each happening on the tick timer.

First of all, make a static method in your `Listener` class as the event handler that you can remove.

```
private static void TickPlay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mmx.Play();
}
```

Then, in your `Subscribe` method, just say:

```
m.Tick += TickPlay;
```

Lastly, for your `Unsubscribe` method, say:

```
m.Tick -= TickPlay;
```

This way it won't keep going Play/Stop ever tick interval.

Comment: What's happening? Is it not starting again? Is it not building?

Comment: It was not recognizing mmx, but i fixed it. When it started to work, it just does not stop. Nothing happens at all :(